# Session Regeneration

Tags: php

I have some confusion with session handling in PHP. I know how to regenerate new session ID in PHP using `session_regenerate_id();`, but I don't understand why and when I should regenerate a new session ID.

I have been googling for some time without avail. No one explains why I need to regenerate a new session ID.

Can someone explain why and when I would need to regenerate a new session ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that regenerating sessions is seen as good, is that it tries to prevent [session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) (or at least limit the damage).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your situation. Most of the time you shouldn't need to regenerate the ID

All you will need is session_start at the top of you pages.

I Would recommend reading the manual on sessions http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: i think it can be useful also in protecting forms with session tokens.